# Sending post data from Joomla to CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, post, joomla

I have a system implemented in CodeIgniter, I am trying to send some data in a text area of Rsform component via POST to the url referring to my CodeIgniter system, I have tried usign AJAX request to send the post data using the following code

```
<script>
alert("jsc");
  var data;
  data='test from joomla!';
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : 'http://localhost/cii/index.php/login/getNews/',
                data: {news:data},
                cache: false,

                success: function(html){
                alert(html);
                }
            });
```

getNews controller:

```
function getNews() {
  //print_r($this->session->userdata);
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  echo "news is ".$news=$_POST['news'];
  $data = array ( 'username' => "null", 'is_logged_in' => false, 'news'=>$news);
  $this->session->set_userdata($data); //var_dump($_POST); //               
  print_r($this->session->userdata); session_start(); echo session_id(); 
}
```

but it failed, is there any other options ?

Comment: And by 'failed' you mean? Some error log maybe? Some description of what you expected to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: do you have any valid options on how to send data from joomla to URL via post, using ajax didn't work it caused me some problems with my session, with each ajax request the session changed

Comment: Can you also post the getNews controller?

Comment: function getNews() 
{ 
//print_r($this->session->userdata);  

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') ;
echo "news is ".$news=$_POST['news'];
$data = array (
'username' => "null",
  'is_logged_in' => false,
  'news'=>$news
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);

//var_dump($_POST);
  //  print_r($this->session->userdata);  
  session_start();
  echo session_id();  
   }

Comment: Please post it in your question, not in the comments

Comment: am sorry the code looks a bit messy, this is the function of the controller am sending the request to

Comment: did you try to `var_dump` youre post as first thing in the getNews function by a request?

Comment: yeah i did that and it didn't retrieve any post data

Comment: did you check the request in firebug? maybe it isn't send at all?

Comment: the request is sent but i think that he is using joomla cookies instead, the post data cannot reach the url referring to my codeignietr system

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Firebug in mozilla firefox to observe what data is being posted to the app to check if your ajax call is working.

Then in your codeigniter controller method, simply put this code to see if the data is getting to it.

```
function getNews()
{  
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val)  
    {  
        $options[$key] = $this->input->post($key);  
    }  

    var_dump($options);      
}
```